# Is there a way to restrict certain java imports via checkstyle or findbugs

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs

We work on a project that depends on many other libraries. These libraries being in other libraries that we would rather not use in our project. But with many developers it is difficult to enforce what kind of libraries we can or cannot use in our project. Is there way in checkstyle or findbugs where we can check for certain imports say

```
import edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays
```

and raise a flag that such imports are not allowed (even though compiler won't complain since this library is part of our project via other library that we depend on.)

Comment: Doubt it, this is not the use case these tools cover. Can you not define and document convention ?

Comment: Defining and documenting convention is easy. I was looking for a tool to enforce it. Are there other tools that can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restrict certain imports you can use any of these Checkstyle rules:

- [ImportControl](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl) to have full control over imports
- [IllegalImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) to prohibit certain imports
- [RegexpSinglelineJava](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava) to simply prohibit occurrences of illegal things in Java classes
- [RegexpMultiline](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline) if you are worried that someone might break illegal import into multiple lines just to avoid being detected